# saveAsTextFile has null output in Spark Steaming via DataBricks

Tags: spark-streaming

The following statement in SCALA as part of Spark Streaming module, 1) creates the part-xxxxx files, 2) but they are all empty in (Databricks). Wondering why this is so, as when output to console it is displayed correctly.

```
QS.foreachRDD(q=> {
       var file=q.map(_.toUpper + "...")
       file.saveAsTextFile("/QS/filexxx")
   })
```

Comment: Community edition

Comment: With 2.0 a few of the Databricks notebooks do not work so well